The icon appears above the text in DatePicker
In my react app I'm using react-datepicker, I added an icon using the showIcon property and it appears above the text. It might be because I'm using right-to-left bootstrap. What can I do to move the text a bit more left.
here my code:
                            <DatePicker
                                className="form-control"
                                showIcon
                                selected={startDate}
                                onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
                                dateFormat="EEEE, d MMMM"
                                locale="he"
                            />

and here how it looks:


https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-calendar-icon - the icon is absolutely positioned, and the input field has padding: 6px 10px 5px 25px - so you probably want to switch the left and right side padding values here.

Why is the text on the right? Can't you just use English alphabet?
